# OperationalError at /admin/auctions/listings/ no such column: auctions_listings.category_id

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to create categories for my listings but it shows the above error.

I also tried adding the id column manually but then it shows  this error:

AssertionError: Model auctions.Category can't have more than one auto-generated field.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser,BaseUserManager
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.conf import settings

# Create your models here.
class myUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    custom user model manager where email is unique indentifiers for authenticaton
    instead of usernames.
    """

    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('The Email must be set'))
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):

        """
        Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password.
        """

        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff',True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser',True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active',True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_staff= True'))
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.'))
        return self.create_user(email,password, **extra_fields)

class myUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = myUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.email}'

class Category(models.Model):

    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="No Category")
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.category}'
    

class Listings(models.Model):
    listing_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    date_listed = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,null=True,blank=True)
    item_image = models.ImageField()
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200, default="Description Not Available")
    listed_by = models.ForeignKey(myUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1,null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.listing_name}'

class Bid(models.Model):
    item_name = models.ForeignKey(Listings,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bid_by_user = models.ForeignKey(myUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    new_bid = models.IntegerField()
```

Please tell me what to do and if there is any better way to do it please do tell me I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Did you run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` after changing the models?

Comment: yes, I did. @AbdulAzizBarkat